# Correct choice for cache database in for visual studio 2013> applications

Tags: sql-server, wcf, caching, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-sync-framework

I have been searching the web for a definitive answer on a question I have regarding local cache database and synchronisation.

I have many projects that were developed several years ago and use SQL Compact 3.5 SP2, sync Framework, SQL 2008 R2 with change Tracking and the local cache database visual studio template.

I was hoping to use something similar as new projects are looming but I need to make sure the technologies used are not nearing end of life and will be supported for a few years to come. SQL Compact 3.5 or 4 does not appear to be the solution to use for this moving forward. Also the local database cache template is no longer available in visual studio 2012+

The clients will most likely be desktop applications, which will need synchronise through WCF services as they will not be allowed to connect directly to SQL Server database.

These projects will be targeting windows 7, windows 10 and potentially windows phone and tablet.

What would be the recommended local database caching solution to use for applications moving forward?

Is it still the sync framework (and if so what local database) or is there something else I should be learning?

Any suggestions very much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: there is no local database cache from VS 2012,they want users to make use of cloud based services like azure

Comment: Ahh - ok - well that makes sense why they removed it - but unfortunately using azure for a local occasionally connected cache database isn't an option. I'll keep investigating. Cheers.